# Why does JSLint tell me to use "=== undefined" instead of "typeof ... === 'undefined'"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jslint

I coded the following:

```
showTitles = (typeof showTitles !== 'undefined') ? showTitles : 'Y';
showSelectGroup = (typeof showSelectGroup !== 'undefined') ? showSelectGroup : 'Y';
```

But JSLint is saying:

> Warning 3 JS Lint: Unexpected 'typeof'. Use '===' to compare directly with undefined.

How should I change my code?

Comment: I don't know anything about jslint, but I think it's telling you to do this: `(showtitles === undefined)`.

Comment: It says it in the message: `Use '===' to compare directly with undefined`.

Comment: `Unexpected 'typeof'` is the problem, not the `!==`.

Comment: You're better off writing `var showTitles = showTitles || 'Y';`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that whether this is best practice in general is debatable, but if you want to make it work with JSLint, you could do this

```
showTitles = (showTitles !== undefined) ? showTitles : 'Y';
```

Comment: @Marilou not if you're using strict comparison. That being said, I would encourage doing research on that and deciding whether you want to do stuff that way for yourself and not just blindly follow JSLint's "advice".

Comment: Have you initialized your variable beforehand? [This code](http://jsfiddle.net/ASfgD/1/) passes JSLint and doesn't have any errors.

Comment: But if you are trying to test whether or not a variable is defined, you have to use typeof. Yet JSLint still complains about it. Very annoying.

Comment: @mattacular Do you have a use case for which comparing to `undefined` does not work properly?

Comment: Yeah... when you are trying to test whether or not a variable is defined. Most of the time, you can refactor your code so that it isn't necessary (someVariable || false) but there are edge cases where you need to test for that and a typeof is the only way I'm aware of to do it safely. For example "aVariableThatMightBeUndefined === undefined" will throw a ReferenceError

Comment: @mattacular you can simply use context for that. `this.aVariableThatMightBeUndefined === undefined`.

Comment: If you need to test of the existence of a global var you must use `typeof`.

Comment: @RicoSonntag no such thing as a "global var" in JavaScript. They all have context you can use.

Comment: @Alex Turpin so would the correct way be
window['variableWhichImTesting'] === undefined

Comment: @szydan yep, you got it!

Answer (score 9):

Probably by using

```
showTitles = (showTitles === undefined) ? 'Y' : showTitles;
showSelectGroup = (showSelectGroup === undefined) ? 'Y' : showSelectGroup;
```

jslint has no issues with that (assuming showTitles and showSelectGroup are declared with var)

However, I'd write it as

```
var showTitles = showTitles || 'Y';
var showSelectGroup = showSelectGroup || 'Y';
```

Answer (score 8):

This message reflects the latest best practices. As of ES5 strict mode, the global value of `undefined` [can no longer be changed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined#Typeof_operator_and_undefined) and a direct comparison is simpler code and faster. In short, [JSLint is aware of all this](https://github.com/jamesallardice/jslint-error-explanations/issues/10#issuecomment-18273885), and is giving you good advice.

In this case, change `typeof showTitles !== 'undefined'` to `showTitles === undefined`.