# why does JSLint recommend x === "undefined" vs. typeof x == "undefined"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined, jslint, typeof

I'm confused with JSLint.

My code originally checked if `div:jqmData("me")` was undefined like so:

```
if ( typeof el.jqmData("me") == "undefined"  
   ? el.not(':jqmData(panel="main")').length > 0 
    : el.not(':jqmData(me="first")').length > 0 ){

}
```

JSLint complains that I should replace checking with `typeof` with `===`, so I did like this:

```
if ( el.jqmData("me") === "undefined"  
   ? el.not(':jqmData(panel="main")').length > 0 
     : el.not(':jqmData(me="first")').length > 0 ){

}
```

JSLint doesn't complain anymore, but my nested if statement is broken, because I'm now always ending up with the 2nd if `el.not(':jqmData(me="first")').length` even when I should not.

**Question**:
Why does JSLint recommend `===` over `typeof == undefined`? How comes this breaks my logic?

Thanks for some enlightment...

Comment: `x === undefined`, not `x === 'undefined'`

Comment: @zerksm: please make it an answer!

Comment: Depending on what you're checking, there's an advantage in using `typeof someVar === 'undefined'` over `someVar === undefined`, namely that the former won't break if `someVar` isn't, in fact, defined. For example, if `someVar` hasn't been declared, you'll get a `ReferenceError` using the latter, while the former works without a hitch. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725603/variable-undefined-vs-typeof-variable-undefined ( cc @zerkms )

Comment: @NullUserException: yep, makes sense for checking variables (as an opposite to properties)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does jslint tell me to use ===?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12628068/why-does-jslint-tell-me-to-use)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've broken the comparison logic. It's assumed you use

```
typeof el.jqmData("me") === "undefined"
```

or

```
el.jqmData("me") === undefined
```

Personally I'd go with the latter.

And personally I think that this particular JSLint check in this particular case makes not much sense.

Comment: yeah. Agree. Thanks for clarification. Good I found this, I have been changing this aplenty...

Comment: But that doesn't work if you want to test that a variable is defined or not: (someundefinedvar === undefined) is a referenceError. Yet JSLint still complains about it even when I am testing variable def.

Comment: @mattacular: yep, I missed that since I don't check that often

Answer (score 0):

What zerkms wrote is correct. An explanation can help though, from https://github.com/jamesallardice/jslint-error-explanations/issues/10#issuecomment-18273885:

A modernization of style has occurred with `undefined` comparison. ES5 guarantees that `undefined` is `undefined`. In strict mode, in comparison with the old and new styles, the `typeof "undefined"` check is longer to type and is no longer necessary now that undefined can be compared directly.

See the JSLint discussion:
https://plus.google.com/101248256976407044060/posts/Q5oFnnxG9oL

Crockford basically says that `typeof "undefined"` check is longer and slower and is unnecessary.