# Jslint does not like !==, seems to prefer ===, relation to typeof

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jslint

```
Unexpected 'typeof'. Use '===' to compare directly with undefined.

    if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
```

This is code from backbone.js.

It does not seem to like the syntax.

How can I change this code to make jslint.com happy?

Comment: This probably has something to do with how `typeof` will not throw a ReferenceError, so you could have `typeof exports === 'undefined'` meaning `exports === undefined` OR that exports is not initialised. Also, JSLint is happy with `!==`, it is the `typeof` with `'undefined'` that it is complaining about.

Comment: It is saying "I want you to check this using `exports !== undefined`".

Comment: what if `undefined` has been defined?

Comment: @JasonSperske: Then clearly one would need to fix it.

Comment: @thesystem but I thought the typeof comparison was meant to survive that

Comment: @JasonSperske you can only define `undefined` in a _modern browser_ if you `var` it outside of the global namespace, use it as the name of a function's parameter or object's key and `with`, as it is [a "non-writable" property of the Global Object "as per the ECMAScript 5 specification"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined)

Comment: @JasonSperske: It is, and that's the problem. If `undefined` has been defined, then it needs to be fixed, but the `typeof` comparison hides the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does jslint tell me to use ===?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12628068/why-does-jslint-tell-me-to-use)

Answer (score 4):

The Underscore library (created by the same guy that made Backbone and CoffeeScript, so you know it's well-thought-out) uses the following for its `isUndefined` function:

```
obj === void 0
```

If you want a fully safe (even in the oddball case of someone redefining `undefined`) approach, that will still make cranky old Crockford (the guy who writes JSLint) happy, I'd use that check.  It's sort of awkward looking though, so at the very least I'd put an explanatory comment with it.

Better yet, you could just roll it up in to your own `isUndefined` function, like Underscore.  Or better yet, you could just use Underscore's function in the first place; if you're using Backbone, you already have Underscore, as Backbone requires it.

Comment: In a kind of perverse irony, the `void 0` check itself does not pass jslint. So we're replacing one construct that doesn't pass jslint with a call to library using another construct that doesn't either.

Comment: ROFL, damn you Crockford!!! ;-)  Seriously though, that's all the more reason to just use Underscore, and leave all the Crockford-hated code out in an library/dependency file, instead of in your organization's code base.  Whatever value JSLint may have (and to be fair, I use it myself), I don't think anyone would argue it's a wise idea to start applying ANY code-checking system, whether it be JSLint or anything else, to code from external libraries.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void, is there a need to put a 0 after it...yes..needs some sort of argument to work.

Answer (score 3):

It appears as though jsLint expects a direct comparison to `undefined` instead of using the `typeof foo === "undefined"` trick.

Using `typeof exports === "undefined"` gives the same error, but using `exports === undefined` passes jsLint:

```
var exports;
var test;

if (exports === undefined) {
    test = "foobar";
}
```

This is a cleaner way to check for `undefined`, and probably less prone to mistakes like `exports === "undefined"` or `typeof exports === undefined`.

Comment: "This is a cleaner way to check ..." Well, except that (as the commenters above have noted) that approach could potentially mask a legitimate error if `undefined` has been defined as something else (oh the joys of Javascript ...).

Comment: @machineghost: Doing `exports === undefined` reveals the error instead of masking it. That was what I was referring to as cleaner.

Comment: Heh, unless someone did `undefined = exports`.  To be fair that's rather unlikely, but technically it is a possibility.

Comment: @machineghost: Yes that's a possibility, and it would need to be fixed. If the coding environment is so volatile that there can be no assurances of `undefined`, then the code should be placed in an IIFE that provides a clean `undefined` variable.

Comment: That's one approach ... or one could just use an `undefined` check that is guaranteed safe ... especially if one already has just such a check lying around in a library that one is already using (as was the case with the OP).

Comment: @machineghost: Yeah, an `isUndefined` function just seems wrong, as does relying on library code for one's `undefined` comparisons even if the library is loaded anyway. I'd opt for the `void` operator over that since at least it's at the language level.

Comment: Well, exactly how much you use libraries is a subjective call, and thus varies from person; everyone should use/not use libraries to taste.  But as for `isUndefined` seeming wrong, let me refer you to my first comment in this thread: "oh the joys of Javascript ..." ;-)

Comment: @machineghost `undefined = exports` won't do much where [`undefined` is non-writable](http://es5.github.com/#x15.1.1.3), so it would already be broken code. It's like saying "you might typo it so call a function instead". There is nothing wrong with using `void` to get an equivalent though.

Comment: @PaulS. "won't do much where `undefined` is non-writable" - you are correct ... and if we lived in a world where every browser magically updated itself to ECMA 5 every Javascript developer's job would be MUCH easier ;-) Unfortunately we live in a world that still has ECMA 3 browsers, and they certainly do allow `undefined` to be written to.  As I've said previously, this is a  corner case, but if you want to truly be safe you have to account for this sort of thing.

Comment: @machineghost: These are all easily solvable problems. Test your code in strict mode, and you'll get an error notifying you of the attempt to write to `undefined`.

Comment: See also good explanation at https://github.com/jamesallardice/jslint-error-explanations/issues/10#issuecomment-18273885: "A modernization of style has occurred with `undefined` comparison. ES5 guarantees that `undefined` is `undefined`. In strict mode, in comparison with the old and new styles, the `typeof "undefined"` check is longer to type and is no longer necessary now that `undefined` can be compared directly.

Answer (score 2):

To assure that undefined has not been redefined:

```
var is_undefined=(function(undefined){
  return function(a){return a===undefined;};
}(/*omitted argument is undefined*/));
```

Taking advantage of the fact that omitted arguments are undefined.

**UPDATE**

An easier way is

```
function is_undefined(x){return x===[][0];}
```

Comment: That's a clever approach.  I still recommend that most readers use libraries to solve problems like this, rather than solving them in a one-off fashion, but if you do want to solve it yourself this seems like a great way to go.

Comment: Why would you do this instead of putting all your code in an IIFE that provides a clean `undefined`. Using a function for a simple value comparison is overkill. Ultimately, if `undefined` has been redefined, it should be revealed, not hidden.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the original question of how to make JSLint happy without the use of functions or alternatives to `typeof`.

The JSLint error message can be bypassed by declaring your result of using `typeof`.

```
var hasExports = typeof exports;
if (hasExports !== 'undefined') {
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function that won't bother jsLint.

```
function getTypeof(obj) {
  'use strict';
  return typeof obj;
}
```

Then you could call the getTypeof function instead of using typeof directly.

```
var exports,
    test;

if (getTypeof(exports) === "undefined") {
    test = "foobar";
}
```

Seems like a lot of extra work and I still don't understand why Crockford objects to using typeof in an if statement.